# Problem with the size of the arrows on a vector field plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know how can I make it so the arrows have a length of sqrt(2) (as their x and y coordinates have length 1). As you can see for the picture shown bellow, they seem quite small. Thanks!
    from pylab import *
    from numpy import ma

```
X = (0, 0, 0)
Y = (0, 1, 2)

quiver(X, Y, (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1))
#axis([0, 1, 0, 3])

show()
```

[alt text http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/6971/arrowsi.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/6971/arrowsi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce arrows sqrt(2) in proportion to the y axis.

```
pylab.quiver(X,Y,(1,1,1),(1,1,1), scale=2**.5, units='y')
```

It was in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver).

Here is an [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html).

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. But that didn't help that much :( I need them to be sqrt(2).